# Using document.addEventListener breaks document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener, getelementbyid

really hope someone can help me out here. Cutting a very long story short, on a few replies on this site I've seen people write that we should move away from:

```
<body onLoad="init();">
```

In the HTML to:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMCONTENTLOADED", init, false);
```

In the JavaScript file so we aren't mixing interactive code with content code etc.

But by switching to this method my code breaks, I can no longer access the DOM tree, here is an example:

```js
function Tester(){
    this.value1 = 10;
    this.container = document.getElementById("fred");
    this.list = this.container.childElementCount;       
    this.in_func = function(){
        alert(this.value1+" "+ this.list);
    };//end of this.in_func
}//end of function Tester
function init(){
    var alpha = new Tester();
    alpha.in_func();
}//end of function init

document.addEventListener("DOMCONTENTLOADED", init(), false);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

  </head>

  <body><!--onLoad="init();"-->
    <section id="fred">
    <section id="elem1"></section>
    <section id="elem2"></section>
    <section id="elem3"></section>
    <section id="elem4"></section>
    <section id="elem5"></section>  
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

The this.container is always null so the childElementCount generates an error of:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childElementCount' of null"

Yet when I comment out the event listener and use the onLoad technique it works, am I just doing something stupid? I've tried using a variable instead of using this.list, tried using querySelector instead of getElementById, I've tried "load" instead of "DOMCONTENTLOADED" but nothing seems to work.

I know it will be something really simple but I cannot find the solution anywhere online, maybe I am just searching for the wrong thing.

Please put me out of my misery.

thanks

Zen

Comment: in: `document.addEventListener("DOMCONTENTLOADED", init(), false);`  init should be a reference - not a call - remove the `()`

ref: 'https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp' -- because you are calling inti() instead of passing a function - your page is still not loaded

Comment: I originally did have it without the parenthesis but then nothing got called at all (no alert message was shown), the function init didn't run at all ( I tested it with an alert in the init function originally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way of doing it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>

function Tester(){
    this.value1 = 10;
    this.container = document.getElementById("fred");
    this.list = this.container.childElementCount;       
    this.in_func = function(){
        alert(this.value1+" "+ this.list);
    };//end of this.in_func
}//end of function Tester
function init(){
    var alpha = new Tester();
    alpha.in_func();
}//end of function init
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  init();
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });

// document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init(), false);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<section id="fred">
<section id="elem1"></section>
<section id="elem2"></section>
<section id="elem3"></section>
<section id="elem4"></section>
<section id="elem5"></section>  
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

In you code you called init() and then passed it, but you should passed it as a function! `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);`
  That's why

Comment: Thanks Armin Neo, that works, I thought I only needed to call it that way if I was parsing arguments to the function. As commented above if I removed the parenthesis in my original call the function wasn't called at all (tried in chrome and FF)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> document.addEventListener("DOMCONTENTLOADED", init(), false);
> ```

## Problem 1

You are calling `init` **immediately** and trying to use its return value as the event handler.

Remove the `()`.

## Problem 2

Event names are case sensitive. It is `DOMContentLoaded` not `DOMCONTENTLOADED`

Comment: Thanks for the case sensitive bit... I had copied it from another post on SO (where they said don't use the onLoad in the HTML)